# What songs are possible to play on a 25-key keyboard?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, midi-controller-keyboard

I am currently quarantined, locked away with a 25-key MIDI keyboard. Are there any songs that only make use of this 25-key range that I can learn? Just two octaves but the controller has the ability to shift these two octaves in either direction, the music just needs to use two side-by-side octaves only.

Just need a list of songs that are possible to play, I do not require a lecture on how having a tiny keyboard isn't good enough. I am already aware. It is just not the best climate to pop to a music shop for a bigger keyboard.

Hopefully there is a wizard on the keys out there who can get me some music to try play.

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Do you have a sequencer or looper? You multi-track record things with a "DAW". First play drums, then bass, then chords, then solo over it with a lead sound. After you have it recorded, mute the chords and bass and invent new chords. Infinite possibilities and no need for special sheet music for 2-octave keyboard.

Comment: So far I have got Beethoven - Ode to joy. I was thinking more along the lines of piano pieces that I can learn the sheet music too. I already make my own house / D&B tracks using the keyboard, just wanting to actually learn some sheet music to up my skills a bit.

Comment: Why not record the bass and treble staves in separate passes into your DAW? Just pick songs that don't extend too far in either direction.

Comment: Not an answer, but.... why not practice a different skill instead, like working out the chords of some songs by ear? Or trying to come up with your own mini keyboard arrangements of songs? 25 keys probably isn't much fun for learning to play from score, but it's plenty for other things. My instrument of choice ATM is an 8-key kalimba...

Comment: you can play everything you want, just when the song goes out of the range of your keyboard you play the r.h. an octave lower respectively  the l.h. an octave higher.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because finding lists or examples of songs are off-topic

Answer (score 2):

Do you necessarily want to use both hands to play the keys? You could try learning pieces meant for a monophonic instrument such as a clarinet, or a polyphonic instrument that can't normally be used for wide chords, like a violin. The best part is that, with your other hand freed, even for compositions that span more than two octaves, you can just switch octaves using the octave change button. You can even use the mod wheel (if you have one) and the volume control to substitute for the lack of access to other techniques. You can even make a game of mapping techniques specific to one instrument to keyboard specific techniques: you can't flutter-tongue, but you can modulate.